# Mariadb: inner join de dos consultas

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tengo una tabla que relaciona reflexiones con categorías a las que pertenece.

```
idReflexion | idCategoria
---------------------------------
      1     |       2
      1     |       3
      1     |       5
      2     |       3
      2     |       5
      3     |       2
      3     |       3
```

Yo quiero que me muestre todas aquellas reflexiones que están en las categorías a,b,c...n

Por ejemplo, si pido que me muestre las reflexiones que pertenecen a las categorías 3 y 5, debería mostrarme la 1 y la 2. Si quiero que me muestre las que pertenecen a las categorías 2 y 3, debería mostrarme la 1 y la 3.

He estado utilizando INNER JOIN de mil y una maneras, pero nada... siempre me da algún error.

Comment: Hola Javi, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio . Puedes añadir la consulta que intentaste y los errores que te salieron? asi será mas facil explicarte qué tienes mal o como mejorarla^^. Para más informacion tienes [ask]. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es mostrar todas las reflexiones que tienen 1 o n categorías
puedes buscarla de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT * FROM reflexiones
 INNER JOIN tabla_relacion ON reflexiones.idReflexion = tabla_relacion.idReflexion 
 INNER JOIN tabla_relacion ON tabla_relacion.idCategoria = categorias.idCategoria 
  WHERE idCategoria in (SELECT idCategoria FROM categorias WHERE idCategoria = 3  
  OR idCategoria = 5)
```

inclusive usando un simple *inner join* debería funcionar

```
SELECT * FROM reflexiones
     INNER JOIN tabla_relacion ON reflexiones.idReflexion = tabla_relacion.idReflexion 
WHERE tabla_relacion.idCategoria = 3 OR tabla_relacion.idCategoria = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Asunto resuelto!

Ejemplo para obtener las reflexiones que están al mismo tiempo en la categoría 18 y en la categoría 19.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.idReflexion FROM esp_reflexioncategoria AS A1 
INNER JOIN esp_reflexioncategoria AS A2 ON (A1.idReflexion = A2.idReflexion AND A2.idCategoria = 19)
WHERE A1.idCategoria = 18
```

Comment: Javi, me alegra que lo solucionaras pero has de estructurar la respuesta como indica en [answer]. Tambien, por favor borra tu otra "respuesta" ya que es una edicion de tu prgunta...Un saludo